# Extract out value from registry key

Tags: windows-registry

i have a registry key and would like to get the value.

However it always prints out the REG_SZ and name of the reg key. May i know how do i get only the value? Thanks!

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us" /v "DisplayVersion"
```

Tried the following but it didn't work for me as well.

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us" /v "DisplayVersion"') do set "value=%%~b"
echo %value%
```

Also tried the following but i'm always getting error "%%a was unexpected at this time" when running using cmd.

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us"  /V DisplayVersion  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') do echo %%a
```

The reg key does exist, just that i'm unable to single out the value only.

[Reg Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mk5m.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352793/reading-a-registry-value-to-a-batch-variable-handling-spaces-in-value

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me. I'm just getting %%a was unexpected at this time. Not sure if it's because of the space in my reg key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use %%a only in batch scripts and %a in the prompt. It won't work the other way round. When you test a command in the prompt you have to edit all the double percentage signs.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared up my confusion